# Installing with pip in a venv and command not found

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

```
> # python3 -m venv venv
> # source venv/bin/activate
> # pip install -e .
```

Installation successful. It's in the bin dir under venv. The path to the bin is in the $PATH env var. And I still get command not found when I type the command in terminal. I tried prepending python3 to the command too (just in case.) No luck!

Comment: is there any reason that you want to use venv or you just need an isolated environment?

Comment: try with another name instead of venv, like `python3 -m venv ./john` seems venv is reserved(?).

Comment: I am using venv because the package maintainer used it and I didn't write things from scratch.

Comment: venv is the environment created for the project I run the command from. Do you know how venv works? I can run the build no problem. I can even install it. I can't find the bin which are there in the venv/bin and that path is into my $PATH. 2022: still dealing with crazy python installation stuff. I had a break with rust/cargo and back to the python sausage machine.

Comment: can you share the package you are working with? are you getting error after trying to run `pip install -e ,` can you confirm `which python3` and `pip --version` are pointing to same python?

Comment: I can use venv as a name too. It's creating a venv directory in the current directory. so that part works. Package installation and dealing with python2 vs python3 version is the most irritating thing with python. Such a shame. it could be so much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Is pip installed correctly?
I understand Python is installed fine, but is pip?
You can verify with `pip --version`

If no: you can reinstall it using the following command:
`sudo apt-get remove python3-pip; sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Comment: Yes, pip is in there. If not the pip install would fail: `pip 21.1.3 from $HOME/package_name/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)

Comment: @JohnDifool What is your output to `python3 -V`?python3 can refer to Python 3.6.9, Python 3.9.1, etc.

Comment: It's installing something somewhere (no error). I just don't know where it puts it. It should be in the packages of the venv but it's not. How do i turn on verbose mode in pip to see what it's doing. The path is udpated with the venv bin path too. but the python lib is not in there either.